# Git hooks to run Laravel migrations automatically

Tags: git, laravel, hook, laravel-migrations

I am about to muddle thru creating 2 hooks, but I just wanted to check if someone has these hooks already, or perhaps a better idea.

pre-push: use git diff --stat --cached origin/master to see if "migrations" are being pushed.  If so, then backup the db before the push.

post-recieve: run migrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Linux you could use a bash script to run your git command. The output command ">" and some grep command could work to determine to check upon your migrations and then execute the laravel migration command.

Comment: ya, that's the plan ~ but with bash... I'm a bit more crash than bash.